# How do I remove comma for Javascript function toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, numbers

I am currently trying to deal with numbers for both English (en) and German (de) languages.
I have a global function which does this and works fine until the number reaches 1000 or more.

```
    function getLocaleString(floatValue) {
    var CurrentCulture = $('#CurrentCulture').val();
    if (CurrentCulture != "" && CurrentCulture != null) {
    return floatValue.toLocaleString(CurrentCulture, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, 
    maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
    }
    return floatValue;
    }
```

Is there a way to get this to remove the comma so the figures do not become distorted?

Comment: `return floatValue.replace(/,/g, '')`

Comment: var tmp ='1,000'; tmp.replace(/,/g, '');

Answer (score 6):

You could set the `useGrouping` option to false.

```
floatValue.toLocaleString(CurrentCulture, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, 
maximumFractionDigits: 2, useGrouping: false });
```

This should avoid the comma for thousand grouping in english and the dot for thousand grouping in german locale.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.toLocaleString()` is language-sensitive, a manual replace is not recommended. Different languages may use different symbols at different locations, as intended. Use a proper number formatter instead.

The most user-friendly and consistent options, without unnecessary regex:

1. Use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) *(recommended: no extra dependency)*:

```js
const number = 123456.789;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"
```

2. Use [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/).

```js
console.log(numeral('10,000.12').format('$0,0.00'));
console.log(numeral(1000).format('0,0'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

3. Other options in the SO post [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)
   .

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `replace()`. Javascript's String replace method

```
floatValue.toLocaleString(CurrentCulture, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, 
    maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).replace(/,/g, "");;
```

`g` modifier is used for global replacement, in order to replace all occurences of the specified value.